# How to use interpolating function for function composition?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions

The following codes give solutions of x(t),y(t), and v(t) as interpolating functions. How to transform y(t) to a regular function so that it can be used for function compostion of y(z(T))? Z(T) is a function defined on solutions of x(t) and y(t). Thanks in advance.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
tstar = -5; Br = 2.5; Dr = 20; b = 1.0548612997205005`; c = 1.0282882725739377`; zfl= 
1.27; R0 = 0.51;

sol1 = NDSolve[{y'[t] == -Sin [x[t]]/y[t],x'[t] == -Cos [x[t]] (6  Sin  [x[t]]  
Cos[x[t]] + y[t] (b - c (1 + 3* y[t]^2)))/(2* y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1))), v'[t] == 
-(b+ c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/(4*y[t]* Cos [x[t]]) + Sin [x[t]]/(2 *y[t]^2), x[tstar] 
==0,y[tstar]== Br, v[tstar] == Log[Dr]}, {x, y, v}, {t, 0, tstar}, Method -> 
{"StiffnessSwitching", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}]
```

The function Z(T) is defined as follows:

```
Z[T_] := 1.88 - NIntegrate[(Cos[x[t] /. sol1])/(y[t] /. sol1), {t, tstar, T}]
```

Comment: Does `x[Z[1]] /. sol1` achieve what you want? If not, what exactly are you after?

Comment: Nope. Actually, I want an (approximate) explicit form of interpolationg funtion of x(t) so that it can be used for function composition.

Comment: Then I am not sure what you mean by "function composition". `InterpolatingFunction` objects can be used just like any other function, e.g. `f = x @* Z /. First@sol1; f[1]`. If you just want a more or less explicit expression for the function, that's a different question

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

tstar = -5; 
Br = 5/2; 
Dr = 20; 
b = 1.0548612997205005` // Rationalize[#, 0] &; 
c = 1.0282882725739377` // Rationalize[#, 0] &; 
zfl = 127/100; 
R0 = 51/100;

{x, y, v} = NDSolveValue[{
    y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]]/y[t],
    x'[t] == -Cos[x[t]] (6 Sin[x[t]] Cos[x[t]] +
         y[t] (b - c (1 + 3*y[t]^2)))/
       (2*y[t]^3*(b + c (y[t]^2 - 1))),
    v'[t] == -(b + c*(y[t]^2 - 1))/
       (4*y[t]*Cos[x[t]]) + Sin[x[t]]/
       (2*y[t]^2),
    x[tstar] == 0, y[tstar] == Br, v[tstar] == Log[Dr]},
   {x, y, v}, {t, 0, tstar},
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching",
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}];

Z[T_?NumericQ] := 47/25 - NIntegrate[(Cos[x[t]])/y[t], {t, tstar, T}]

Plot[Z[t], {t, tstar, 0}]
```

[image]

Note that the values of `Z[t]` are outside of the time range for which `x[t]` and `y[t]` are defined, i.e., `-5  <=  t <= 0`.

```
Plot[{x[Z[t]], y[Z[t]]}, {t, 0, tstar},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.7, .4}]]
```

[image]